# How to prevent on click event to fire twice

Tags: android, jquery

I'm trying to manage events in firetv app, the problem is on event fires Enter key and Click key at the same time, how can I prevent that?

Tried to use inEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); but it still does not help.

```
$(document).on('click keydown', '.currentSlide', function (inEvent) {
       var keycode;
       var logger = $('#error-logger');

       if(window.event) {
           keycode = inEvent.keyCode;
       } else if(e.which) {
           keycode = inEvent.which;
       } if (inEvent.type === 'click') {
           keycode = 1;
       }

       console.log(`Keycode: ${keycode}`);
});
```

Clicking the remote button triggers the event twice and I'm trying to get it to only do it once.

Comment: Yes I need both events since for example LG has cursor and that triggers Click event but firetv triggers enter event only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding 1 more var that I set to true on keydown and on keyup to false again.

I'm not sure if there is better way of doing it but this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following as the first line in your function before you do anything

```
inEvent.stoppropagation()
```

this will stop any further events from triggering.

Comment: This is not accurate for several reasons. Firstly, it's `stopPropagation()` not `stoppropagation()`. Secondly, it stops events bubbling up the DOM. It does not stop 'further events from happening'. Thirdly, even if it did stop events, it would only stop the *same type* of event happening, not different ones.